# Matplotlib run and raise error (MatplotlibDeprecationWarning)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm running a pie plot and the plot work but it will raise an error.  im net to matplotlib so how should i fix this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame(3 * np.random.rand(4, 2), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df.plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(15, 8))
plt.show()
```

and the error is :

```
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The colNum attribute was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.2 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use ax.get_subplotspec().colspan.start instead.
  if not layout[ax.rowNum + 1, ax.colNum]:
```

Comment: In my environment, MPL 3.3.1 did not give me any warnings. This is a warning, so I think it's safe to ignore it.

Comment: @r-beginners I write a print after it. and didn't wok. so I wanna fix it for future Collisions.

Comment: `df.plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(15, 8), layout=(1,2))` Will this stop the error?

Comment: @r-beginners still have the same erorr

Comment: I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60571214/pandas-scatter-matrix-is-returning-the-error-the-rownum-attribute-was-deprecate) that if I brought pandas up to date, it solved the problem.